# Convert expression from C# into Java

Tags: c#, java, string, long-integer

I am to convert a C# program into Java. At one point I really don't get what is done, there. I changed the code to clarify the types and give an example.

```
string myString = "Test";
long l = (long)myString[0];
```

1) What is the [0] doing with a normal string? Is that even possible? Is it just the substring, in this case "T"?

2) How could you cast a String or character to long, if the String represents a text?

Comment: Btw the cast is redundant as this is not a narrowing conversion.

Comment: +1 for leveling. Maybe Manuel is not fluent in English. And anyway there are two related questions numbered as (1) and (2). For me it's pretty clear he wants to understand what's happening here (for eventually translate it to Java).

Comment: As I said, all answers were helpful. I decided to accept helios' answer because, at first, he was the only one who provided the example in Java. And, his explanation, as short as it might be, did help me understand what was going on in C# (because in the end it wasn't hard to understand, I kinda feel stupid that I asked).
But I have to admit that Abel's answer would've been a good choice, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's converting a char code to long. In Java you would have to:

```
long l = (long) myString.charAt(0)
```

Comment: Thanks @ all for clarifying this. All answers were helpful and I mark this one as accepted for giving the example in Java.

Answer (score 3):

> `long l = (long)myString[0];`

the index of a string gives the char. A `char` is castable as a `long`. This will give you the long-value (unicode value) of the character in the first position of the string, i.e., `A` will be `65`.

The cast `(long)` is not needed in C#, because `char` has what's called a "implicit cast operator" for `long` and  `int`. The following statement is just as well correct:

> `long l = myString[0];`

The equivalent of `char` in C# is `char` in Java, albeit that implementations are slightly different. In Java, a char can be cast to an `int` or a `long`. To get the character, use `CharAt()`.

Answer (score 1):

A string is an array of characters, so that makes it possible to access given position.

Having said that, myString[0] is accessing the first char, 'T'.

You can then cast a char to a long, converting it to its ASCII position value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this converter http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/index.htm - the trial version is able to convert some amount of lines for free :)

Comment: You could also use IKVM and not having to convert anything. It just works under .NET.